# Outlook C# move an email into a mailbox associated with a MS365 Group

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am writing a C# VSTO addin to provide some email filing helper functions. I am stuck as to how  can programmatically move an email I have received into the conversations mailbox associated with an MS365 Group. The group itself is created as part of a sharepoint modern team site.
I can manually drag emails over to the group mailbox, but I cannot find a way to obtain the folder object in C#.

Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2111 Build 16.0.14701.20254) 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.move) method of Outlook items.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.NewMail += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
        ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailEventHandler
        (ThisAddIn_NewMail);

}

private void ThisAddIn_NewMail()
{
    Outlook.MAPIFolder inBox = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)this.Application.
        ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
        (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    Outlook.Items items = (Outlook.Items)inBox.Items;
    Outlook.MailItem moveMail = null;
    items.Restrict("[UnRead] = true");
    Outlook.MAPIFolder destFolder = inBox.Folders["Test"];
    foreach (object eMail in items)
    {
        try
        {
            moveMail = eMail as Outlook.MailItem;
            if (moveMail != null)
            {
                string titleSubject = (string)moveMail.Subject;
                if (titleSubject.IndexOf("Test") > 0)
                {
                    moveMail.Move(destFolder);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose the destination folder is listed in Outlook in an additional store. So, you can use the [Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.stores) property of the `Namespace` class to find the target folder.

Comment: the move function was my first thought too. Trouble is that I cannot get a destination folder object to use as a target. When I put a break in my code and look at the selected item in the locals window, the messages I moved manually do not have a store. The Item.parent.store variable is null. The parent does have a StoreID, but I don't know if/how I can use that to obtain a destination folder object.

Comment: The Item parent does have a FolderPath "\\\\email@addres.com\\Conversations\\JV22-12345 Test Site 2". Again, I do not know if/how I can translate this into the folder. I tried iterating through the folders object of the root folder obtained using the namespace default store, but 'conversations' does not exist as a sub-folder.